# Exhaustion of a manifold by open $n$-cells

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that a differentiable manifold $M^n$ has an exhaustion $M^n=\bigcup U_i$ with $U_i \subset U_{i+1}$ such that each element $U_i$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Can we prove that $M^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?

Notice that if $n\ne 4$, the question is true from [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2034881.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Aaa75053b2d50f388d6d13596c55c5456) since there is a unique smooth structure on $\mathbb R^n$. So the question only concerns four-dimensional case.

Comment: Sorry for a naïve question, but how can one deduce that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ from the uniqueness of smooth structure on $\mathbb R^n$?  It seems you'd need first to know that $M$ is a topological $\mathbb R^n$; is that obvious?

Comment: @LSpice: You didn't follow the link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177579/manifold-with-a-good-exhaustion?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065755/characterization-of-mathbbrn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess the link you gave requires all $\bar U_i \subset U_{i+1}$ and all $\bar U_i$ is diffeomorphic to a closed $n$-ball.

Comment: If $U_i$ is diffeo to $R^n$, it contains arbitrarily large smooth compact $n$-balls $V_i$; this yields an exhaustion by $int(V_i)$ such that $V_i\subset int(V_{i+1})$.